# How do tag blocklists work?

Tags: support, tags, privileges, blocked-tags

I've just discovered the [tag-block-request](/questions/tagged/tag-block-request) questions on this meta, and wondered how and when this feature is used.

For example, I just discovered that we had a [code](/questions/tagged/code) tag ([link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code)) on Electrical Engineering, which was variously used for source code, binary codes, color codes, and official standards.  All that, in 7 questions (which I've since edited to remove the tag).  None of these is obviously the main target of the word [code](/questions/tagged/code), so I conclude that the [code](/questions/tagged/code) tag is meaningless, and should be abolished.

- Is a tag blocklist an appropriate action for this tag?  How do you decide which tags to block?
- Assuming that the blocklist is appropriate,how can the blocklist be created?  I don't see a way to add anything to the [blocklist page](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/admin/blocklist), and there's no mention of this privilege in the tools that I can find.

Comment: FAQ proposal with a more compresehensive, detailed answer: [What is a blocked tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295148/what-is-a-blocked-tag)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The StackExchange Developer Staff are the only ones who have the ability to  blocklist tags.  That's why you have to post a [tag-block-request] here.

Tags are typically blocked when wide consensus is reached that the tag is bad, and the tag keeps reappearing on the site, despite repeated attempts to obliterate it.

See [this blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) for a detailed discussion on the merits (and demerits) of certain tags, and when they become potential candidates for blocking.

Comment: Does "here" mean on [meta.stackoverflow.com](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/), or on a [per-site meta](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/)?  Also, how is "wide consensus" determined?

Comment: @Kevin: The blog post I linked is a good illustration of the thought pattern that goes into "wide consensus."  Consensus for a specific [tag-blacklist-request] is accomplished via the meta request, and the answers it receives. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tag-blacklist-request+status-completed) for a list of successful blacklist requests.

Comment: Tag blacklist requests for specific sites should be made on the site-specific meta, so that the appropriate community can discuss them. It is my understanding that the developer staff monitors the site-specific metas for posts with certain tags such as [tag-blacklist-request].